# getJSON, give back 2 different arrays

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

Is it possible with getJSON, to pass 2 different arrays?

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>', {
    ajax: 'ajax_article_partlist' ,
    parent_article: $('#selected_article').val()
},
function(data) {
     $('#articles').html('');
     $('#article_table').show('slide');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#articles').append("<p>"+data[i]+"</p>");
        }
});
```

this is my request ,on php side i echo and array. But i got now a second array i have to pass in same request. So is that possible, or do i have to make a new getJSON?

php code:

```
    case 'ajax_article_partlist' :
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $form->addFormField(new FW_HTML_Form_Request('parent_article'));

    $form->resolveRequest();

    $parent_article = $form->getValue('parent_article');
    $part_list =$db_obj->getFormatedPartList($parent_article);
    $db_obj->checkArticleProgram($parent_article);

    echo json_encode($part_list);
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/includes/cms.footer.inc');
    exit;
    break;
```

Comment: Why don´t you make a JSON object with two arrays?

Comment: i dont know how? probably thats why i posted the question... :)

Comment: where is first and second array in php ? `echo json_encode($part_list);` ?

Comment: this is just the first array, dont know where to implement the second one but its this : ` $db_obj->checkArticleProgram($parent_article);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are array syntax details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

```
echo json_encode(array("part_list" => $part_list, "second_array" => $second_array));
```

And than in getJSON success function:

```
function(data) {
     $('#articles').html('');
     $('#article_table').show('slide');
     for (var i = 0; i < data.parts_list.length; i++) {
            $('#articles').append("<p>"+data.parts_list[i]+"</p>");
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < data.second_array.length; i++) {
           //do somethign with second array
     }
}
```

Comment: uhh well ye that was obvious , i just overthought it as usualy..   Thx

Answer (score 4):

My PHP is a bit rusty, but this might work:

```
$two_arrays = array(
    "array1" -> $part1_list,
    "array2" -> $part2_list
);

echo json_encode($two_arrays);
```

And on your client side you can access the arrays as `data.array1` and `data.array2`

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
$json=new stdClass();
$a=array('a'=>1);
$b=array('b'=>2);
$json->a=array();
$json->b=array();
$json->a=$a;
$json->b=$b;
echo json_encode($json);
```